# SFML под Android - ошибка установки

Tags: android, c++, sfml

Пытаюсь установить SFML под Android по этой доке: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Building-SFML-for-Android

Но возникла ошибка:

```
C:\work\SFML\build\armeabi>cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=..
/../cmake/toolchains/android.toolchain.cmake ../..
CMake Error at cmake/toolchains/android.toolchain.cmake:802 (message):
Specified Android native API level 'android-9' is not supported by your
NDK/toolchain.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
build/armeabi/CMakeFiles/3.9.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:62 (project)


CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMak
eForceCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated. Instead just set
CMAKE_C_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/toolchains/android.toolchain.cmake:1153 (CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER)
build/armeabi/CMakeFiles/3.9.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:62 (project)


CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMak
eForceCompiler.cmake:83 (message):
The CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER macro is deprecated. Instead just set
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/toolchains/android.toolchain.cmake:1165 (CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER)
build/armeabi/CMakeFiles/3.9.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:62 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:62 (project):
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is 'Android' but 'NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Visual Studio
Edition' is not installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/work/SFML/build/armeabi/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Как решить проблему?